# Obtaining the $n$-sphere by gluing two copies of $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I want to show that the $n$-sphere $S^n$ is obtained by gluing two copies of $\mathbf{R}^n$ along the map $\varphi : \mathbf{R}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbf{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ defined by $x \to \frac{x}{\|x\|^2}$.

I checked that this map is a diffeomorphism, hence $\mathbf{R}^n \coprod_\varphi \mathbf{R}^n$ is well-defined.

Intuitively (ie: with a drawing), I see why the result is true, but I don't know how to define a diffeomorphism $\mathbf{R}^n \coprod_\varphi \mathbf{R}^n \to S^n$, and how to use the gluing map.

Comment: Suggestion: Do you know about stereographic projection (from the north and south poles)?

Comment: I do. In fact I have remarked that $\varphi = \varphi_N \circ \varphi_S^{-1}$, those being the local charts for $S^1$.

Comment: Use stereographic projection from $N$ on the first copy of $\mathbf{R}^n$ and projection from $S$ on the second copy; check this is (i) well-defined and (ii) bijective from the identification space to the sphere. <> Please feel free to write up and post the details!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. However I found myself struggling to write an application $f : S^1 \to \mathbf{R}^n \coprod \mathbf{R}^n$.
$x \to (\varphi_N(x), \varphi_S(x))$ seems wrong, and $x \to \begin{cases} (\varphi_S(x), 1) \\ (\varphi_N(x),2)\end{cases}$ too.